# How does the PDE $\,\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2} = 0\,$ become $\,u=x\,f(y)+g(y)\,$ when integrated?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Given that $u(x,y)$ can someone please explain to me how the result as asked in the question is achieved? Steps would be really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $u_{xx}=0$ implies that $$ u_x= f(y) 
$$

(Here fix $y_0$. Then $u_x(x,y_0)$ is a function of variable $x$ only. If $u_{xx}=0$ then $u_x$ is constant : If not, that is, for example $u_x(x_1) < u_x(x_2)$, then note that by mean value theorem, $$ u_x(x_1)-u_x(x_2)= u_{xx} (x_3)(x_1-x_2),\ x_3\in [x_1,x_2] $$ for some $x_3$. So we have a contradiction. )

And $$ u=xf(y)+g(y)$$

Comment: thank you for your response! is there any way you could explain how you get from uxx=0 to ux=f(y) please?

Comment: I add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's analogous to $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$$.  The solution to this is obtained by saying $\frac{dy}{dx}=k_1$ (a constant, not a function of $x$).
So $$y=k_1x+k_2$$ where $k_2$ is another constant, not a function of $x$.
In your example with partial derivatives $f(y)$ and $g(y)$ are like the constants $k_1$ and $k_2$, since their partial derivatives with respect to $x$ are zero.